# Threading and QRegisterMetatype issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have develop an app in Qt/C++, the app is currently working in one thread and and based on a UI and a framework. the UI and framework discuss together using the signal/slot mecanism provided by Qt. I have added threading because some operation inside the framework freeze UI.

The issue I'm facing is that now the app is not working anymore because of

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'uint32_t'
(Make sure 'uint32_t' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

What I have done is, declare in the main the qRegisterMetatype but it still complaining. I don't really know what I have to do in addition.

I have gave you below the basic process for a deletion for example.

main.cpp

```
qRegisterMetaType<uint32_t>("uint32_t");
qRegisterMetaType<QList<QTreeWidgetItem*> >("QList<QTreeWidgetItem*>");
```

Treewidget.cpp

```
void TreeWidget::DeleteAction() {
    ....
    connect(this,&PulsTreeWidget::RequestDelete, &m_Framework, &PulsFramework::DeleteItem);
    emit RequestDelete(item, nb_items);
}
```

Framework.cpp

```
void Framework::DeleteItem(QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> item, uint32_t total_item) {...}
```

Any idea ? do I need to not use the uint32_t as it is but change it's definition

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something worng. My example:

**Object.h**

```
#ifndef OBJECT_H
#define OBJECT_H

#include <QtCore>

class Object : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Object(QObject *parent = 0);

    void emitSignal(uint32_t v);

public slots:
    void mySlot(uint32_t v);

signals:
    void mySignal(uint32_t v);
};

#endif // OBJECT_H
```

**Object.cpp**

```
#include "Object.h"

Object::Object(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

void Object::emitSignal(uint32_t v)
{
    emit mySignal(v);
}

void Object::mySlot(uint32_t v)
{
    qDebug() << v;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Object.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    qRegisterMetaType < uint32_t >("uint32_t");    // <--------------

    Object o1, o2;
    QThread t1, t2;

    o1.moveToThread(&t1);
    o2.moveToThread(&t2);

    QObject::connect(&o1, SIGNAL(mySignal(uint32_t)), &o2, SLOT(mySlot(uint32_t)));
    QObject::connect(&o2, SIGNAL(mySignal(uint32_t)), &o1, SLOT(mySlot(uint32_t)));

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    o1.emitSignal(5);
    o2.emitSignal(10);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**Output:**

```
5
10
```

When removing `qRegisterMetaType < uint32_t >("uint32_t");` line, also complains:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'uint32_t'
(Make sure 'uint32_t' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'uint32_t'
(Make sure 'uint32_t' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

P.S.: I don't like your connect+emit pair. You do know, that you need to connect signal to slot only once in order it to work? You do not need to do it before each signal emit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is really the best solution and the easiest way to implement as well